# Styling radio button label with javascript, only one label get colored

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello I'm trying to color the label of a radio button when it is `checked`

I don't understand why it only works for the first radio button: `Mon`

When I'm checking Mon, it gets red but when I check `Tue`, `Mon` goes black but `Tue` is black instead of red why is that?

```
<ul>
  <li><input type="radio" id="day" name="day" value="Mon" onclick="myFunction()"></li>
  <label id="daylab" for="day">Mon</label>

  <li><input type="radio" id="day" name="day" value="Tue" onclick="myFunction()"></li>
  <label id="daylab" for="day">Tue</label>
```

```
function myFunction() {
    var checkBox = document.getElementById("day");

    if (checkBox.checked == true){
        document.getElementById("daylab").style.color = "red";
    } else {
         document.getElementById("daylab").style.color = "black";
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ids are uniques in HTML, so that markup is invalid and causes that your logic is not working properly.

Try to set a name rather than ids and work over it.

**This is an alternative to set a specific color to the sibling `label`**

- Finds the closest parent `ul` and removes the class `active`.
- Then, finds the closest `li` and adds the class `active` to the sibling `label`.

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('[name="day"]'), function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('change', myFunction);
});

function myFunction() {
 Array.prototype.forEach.call(this.closest('ul').querySelectorAll('.active'), function(activeElem) {
  activeElem.classList.remove('active');
});

  this.closest('li').querySelector('label').classList.add('active');
}
```

```css
.active {
  color: lightgreen
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <label for="day">Mon</label>
    <input type="radio" name="day" value="Mon">
  </li>

  <li>
    <label for="day">Tue</label>
    <input type="radio" name="day" value="Tue">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use css to do that

```
input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  color: red;
}
```

HTML tidied up:

```
<ul>
  <li><input type="radio" id="day" name="day" value="Mon">
    <label id="daylab" for="day">Mon</label></li>

  <li><input type="radio" id="day" name="day" value="Tue">
    <label id="daylab" for="day">Tue</label></li>
</ul>
```

[Running example](https://jsfiddle.net/ddan/7vxqa5oL/1/)

Comment: Thank you ! I didn't know I could do it with css only

Answer (score 0):

i use pure css for personalize input radio! 
example:

```
input[type=radio]:checked 
{
    background: #F00;
}
```

but before use this code, normalize input radio with this code:

```
input[type=radio]
 {
    padding: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 30px;
    outline: none;
    margin: 2px;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! I didn't know I could do it with css only